# rails 3 blog engine/gem that works on heroku, what to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, blogs, rails-engines

I have spent some time looking for a rail3 blog engine for use on an existing site. I want the blog on the same domain as the application for SEO points eg www.site.com/blog not blog.site.com

Having spent some time on this I have found:

- Toto
- Jekyll.
  Which generate static pages, I really like this idea as its optimal under-load as its highly cached. Not sure how our not technical blog writers will cope with this.

Also I looked at more dynamic platforms like:

- typo (which seams dated, I guess they are finding it hard to port to rails 3)
- mephisto

Are people giving up on this as this post [Need to link WP Blog with Rails App on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130795/need-to-link-wp-blog-with-rails-app-on-heroku) suggests? Seams crazy given the value of this. Also, this post was good but not really conclusive for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807670/blog-engine-for-rails-application.

Comment: Any particular reason it needs to be rails3?

Comment: We are using rails 3 for our main app.

Comment: What features do you need the blogging engine to have? Rich text editing? User accounts? Comments? If so, any particular kind of spam control (e.g. reCaptcha; Akismet; etc)? Automatic pingback/trackback handling?

Comment: All the features you mention are needed or at least preferred. We would want the blog to be engaging. It doesnt matter if the blog connects with some other tool though, for instance, if it used http://disqus.com/ for comments, that would work for me.

Comment: The SO community can't really make those decisions for you. I'd suggest you consider your requirements a bit more precisely and then rewrite your question accordingly. For instance, if you "need or prefer" the engine to have manage comments, then Jekyll is unsuitable for you. On the other hand, if you're happy to use Disqus, then Jekyll might be OK for you. In other words, to help the SO community to help you, please reformulate your question to make it a "real" question (to use SO's vocabulary...).

Comment: Have you used any of these on rails 3? From what I can tell none of the ones I listed work well in rails 3. The question is which route to follow. I am happy to compromise on features for a blogging gem that works and will scale.

Comment: (and in heroku) that should say

Comment: No, I haven't :) I was just trying to be helpful, partly because I'm curious about the answer to your question too, and I'd like to see it made into one that's likely to receive more answers.

Comment: Yeah, my question is so open because I just couldn't find anything other than hacky solutions on seemingly outdated gems (someone please do show me if I am wrong on this). Also, I do like the help you offered - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've been really impressed by monologue, so far.

https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue

It's a bare-bones db-backed blog engine.

Comment: Eliza -- have you done any customization to monologue? For example, adding additional models/relationships to the blog tags and posts?

Answer (score 0):

One of the creators of heroku wrote a small [blog engine](https://github.com/adamwiggins/scanty).

https://github.com/adamwiggins/scanty